# App opens then immediately closes - iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

When I "run" my app from XCode the simulator comes up and the app attempts to run, it animates to a black screen for a second and then the app closes immediately.

The app was running fine before and now suddenly won't work.

There is no output on the console, no errors or anything and the app isn't crashing (as far as I can tell).

I have tried deleting all my user specific files in the xcodeproj package, but this hasn't changed anything.

Is there any other reason why this would happen? How do I fix this?

Thank you.

ADDITION: `NSLog(@"something");` in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method doesn't show up on the console.

Comment: Maybe there are some logs in the console app of your mac

Comment: @Thomas Clayson It's inside your application/utilities folder http://www.apple.com/macosx/apps/all.html#console

Comment: If you have a Unit Test target, make also sure that you do not run for testing...

Comment: Have you tried blitzing the app from the simulator and the deriveddata directory.  Remove ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/<application directory> and ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<application directory>.  Where application directory is a complex ID (use ls to determine which) or your application name followed by a hash respectively. Also the Product->Clean option in XCode will change to a Clean Build Folder... option if you hold down alt.  Which may/may not help.

Comment: In console I get this: `25/04/2012 13:54:51.536 SpringBoard: Launchd returned an unexpected type or didn't return a value for job label UIKitApplication:... with job key PID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reboot of my Mac seems to have fixed it. Thanks guys for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a new Xcode(4+) and previously 3, there may be issue. Try setting the Architectures (Target -> Build Settings -> Architectures) to support armv6 too, presently it supports armv7(standard) only. If my memory is not deceiving me I guess I had such an issue.

Comment: In my experience, architecture problems will cause the app not to be transferred to the device at all.